# How do I get a div to display a specific image when a user mouses over either of two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the div with the class `features_3_content_center` to display the `FH_MainMenu.png` image when a user mouses over the div with id `FH_Blurb`, or display the `HDS_MainMenu.png` image when a user mouses over the div with id `HDS_Blurb`.

I've attempted this below by having both images on top of each other in `features_3_content_center` and having it display the image based on its id. This doesn't seem to work, it just displays the first image (HDS_MainMenu.png) and doesn't change on mouseover. What am I doing wrong?

```js
PicChanger: function() {
  $('#FH_Blurb').mouseover(function() {
    $('.features_3_content_center').getElementById('#features3_FH_image');
  });
  $('#HDS_Blurb').mouseover(function() {
    $('.features_3_content_center').getElementById('#features3_HDS_image');
  });
},
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_left">
    <div class="feature" id="FH_Blurb">
      <h4>Fizz+Hummer</h4>
      <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4">
    <div class="features_3_content_center">
      <img src="images/HDS_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_HDS_image" alt="img">
      <img src="images/FH_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_FH_image" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_right">
    <div class="feature" id="HDS_Blurb">
      <div>
        <h4 class="we_make_games_HDS_text">Human Delivery Service</h4>
        <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2hL71dsr/

Comment: Does the solution have to use Jquery? This could be easily solved with CSS alone.

Comment: This is not a valid `jQuery` selector: `$('.features_3_content_center').getElementById('#features3_FH_image');`

Comment: $('.features_3_content_center').getElementById('#features3_FH_image'); is incorrect syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of like this:

```
$('#features3_FH_image, #features3_HDS_image').hide();           

$('#FH_Blurb').hover(function() {
  $('#features3_FH_image').toggle();
});

$('#HDS_Blurb').hover(function() {
  $('#features3_HDS_image').toggle();
});
```

See it in action [**in this demo**](http://www.bootply.com/vtGzcqXsFC)

Comment: This works, but only for the `#FH_Blurb`, when I mouse over `#HDS_Blurb`, it doesn't show anything. I tried having the `#HDS_Blurb` show `#features3_FH_image` instead, and that worked. Both images exist in the folder, so what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually doing anything to the images. Here is a simple, straight-forward method of showing the images on mouseover, then hiding them again on mouseout.

```
var imgContainer = $('.features_3_content_center');
var FH_image = imgContainer.find('#features3_FH_image').hide();
var HDS_image = imgContainer.find('#features3_HDS_image').hide();
$('#FH_Blurb').on('mouseover', function() {
  FH_image.show();
});
$('#FH_Blurb').on('mouseout', function() {
  FH_image.hide();
});
$('#HDS_Blurb').on('mouseover', function() {
  HDS_image.show();
});
$('#HDS_Blurb').on('mouseout', function() {
  HDS_image.hide();
});
```